# Dataframe Index row comparison and removal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

Good day,

I need a bit of advice I have two dataframes. One containing hundrends of lines and another containing six. Timestamps are indexed for both frames. I want to compare index values in df1 with df2 and keep only the rows that match the timestamp in df2.

```
df1
Date-Time                A    B    C    D
2012-01-11 7:10:05:00    0    1    2    3
2012-01-11 7:14:05:00    0    1    2    3
2012-01-11 7:16:05:00    0    1    2    3
2012-01-11 7:25:05:00    0    1    2    3
2012-01-11 7:31:05:00    0    1    2    3

df2
Date-Time                A    B    C    D
2012-01-11 7:10:05:00    6    8    1.5  6.8
2012-01-11 7:25:05:00    0    11   4    3.3
2012-01-11 7:31:05:00    0    44   2.2  3.3
```

So only rows 0, 3 and 4 should be remaining in d1

Comment: Is `Date-Time` the index, or a column?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your 'Date-Time' column is the `index` in both (you can get it by `set_index()`, and then pick 1:

**1)** Use `isin`:

```
df1_new = df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

**2)** Use `loc`:

```
df1_new = df1.loc[df2.index, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your index to column, then follow instructions in below link after which you can change it back to index

[Compare two pandas dataframe with different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414876/compare-two-pandas-dataframe-with-different-size)

Answer (score 0):

If `Date-Time` is a column, try this:
`df1 = df1[ df1['Date-Time'] == df2['Date-Time'] ]`

You can also do it by merging the data frames:

```py
df1 = pd.merge(df2['Date-Time'], df1, on='Date-Time', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it
`df1.loc[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]`