# Comparing data frames with different size

Tags: python, dataframe, compare

I'm comparing two different size data frames. (a column in first data frame has 1000 members and I'm comparing it with a column in another data frame that has 48 members) and I'm getting this error.

"Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

the code is:

```
df2['present_in_df1'] = np.where(df1['Names'] == df2['Names'], "yes", "no")
```

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414876/compare-two-pandas-dataframe-with-different-size may this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy.where with isin().

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
name1=['A','B','C']
name2=['B','C']
df1=pd.DataFrame({'name':name1})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name':name2})
#using numpy 
df2['present_in_df1'] = np.where(df2.name.isin(df1.name), 'Yes', 'No')
df2.head(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```py
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'a': [1,2,3,4,2,2,2]}
d2 = {'b':[1,2,5,6]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df2['present_in_df1'] = df2['b'].isin(df1['a'])

print(df2)

   b  present_in_df1
0  1            True
1  2            True
2  5           False
3  6           False
[Finished in 0.38s]
```